# Java BOT on MAVEN (with JDA libraries) run on Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, bots, discord

I have done a project in IntelliJ with Maven. It's a bot written in Java. It receives a request, processes it, and sends a response to the person who asked.

When I deploying the project from my GitHub repository to Heroku- it deploys successfully.

[image]

But when I open the project, Heroku shows me this:
[image]

I'm sure I have problems with **`Procfile`**, as I don't know how to manage, and possibly I have issues with **`pom.xml`**

**Procfile**:

```
worker: java -jar out/artifacts/lancebot_jar/lancebot.java
```

**pox.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lancebot</groupId>
    <artifactId>lancebot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0_427</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: run `heroku logs` and share the output

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your `Procfile`:

```
worker: java -jar out/artifacts/lancebot_jar/lancebot.java
```

The `worker` process type won't get a web port. It won't serve a web page unless it's called `web:`.

The `java` command is invalid. You've passed it a `.java` file, and not a `.jar`